# Can I buy a domain name from one service and host a web app on another service?

Tags: python, django, web, heroku, django-models

I bought a domain name from a service called gandi .However, it is not the best to host a Django web app. I am considering to switch to heroku. Does anyone has tips or advices when hosting a Django web app?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can [use your own domain with Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#summary-of-steps).  Of course.

Their command line API has commands for doing this. `heroku domains:add www.example.com` is the key to it.

But you also need to tell your DNS provider to point to Heroku. The linked article mentions the steps. The precise ways of doing it depend on your DNS provider's user interface.

Be patient. DNS changes can take hours to propagate.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, there should be some way for you to route (using DNS records) from your domain bought at gandi.net to e.g. a heroku app.

Go into the configuration of your domain on gandi.net and look for a way to change either which IP, or CNAME your domain points to.

Comment: Are you implying the concept of web forwarding?